# Why tensorflow would automatically continue training the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running my python-project which is about training a neural network with tensorflow at PyCharm, and find that my network has been already well-trained since the second restart of running my project.

I have no command to restore any trained model in my project (I do have commands for saving models). Anyone knows anything about my problem?
Is it possible that tensorflow or pycharm have default settings to save and restore?

Great thanks!

Comment: Did you check the time file was created,modified to verify ? Usually such things dont happen. There must be some related code for the same.

Comment: Yeah, I did check those files, but nothing wired to be found. This happens after I add codes to save the network model, but the problem is not fixed even I delete those codes.